# When changing one specific state setting, is it necessary to restate all the other ones?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Let's say, I have a state that looks as follows.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    setting_a: "value-1",
    setting_b: "color-green"
  }
}
```

When I change the state of a specific setting (e.g. `setting_a`), I don't want other settings (e.g. `setting_b`) to disappear. So I also specify the other settings while changing the state. (which is easy using the spread operator `...state`).

```
this.setState( {...this.state, setting_a: "value-2"});
```

**I noticed though, that some tutorials restate them, and others only specify the changed key-values.**

Things got just a little bit more complicated since the introduction of the `Component#getDerivedStateFromProps` method, ( since React 16.3 ).

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  const oldSetting = state.setting_a;
  const newSetting = props.setting_a;

  if (oldSetting !== newSetting) {
    // this is a very similar situation.
    return ({ ...state, state.setting_a: props.setting_a});
  }
  return null;
}
```

Again, in the above example, I add all previous settings (i.e. `...state`), because I don't want the other settings to be removed.

In both these cases, the same question: **do I need to specifically repeat values which are already in the state ? Or are the states always merged incrementally, without removing ?**

Comment: do I need to specifically repeat values which are already in the state ? You do not need to you are already using ...state Or are the states always merged incrementally, without removing ? no, state do not know what are properties there it needs to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to copy the state (using spread operator or any idea) when updating the state with setState. The `setState` method updates the required state only:

```
this.setState( {setting_a: "value-2"});
```

So, now you will still get:

```
state = {
    setting_a: "value-2",
    setting_b: "color-green"
  }
```

Similarly, it works like that when you return the object in `getDerivedStateFromProps`. The returned value is applied in the state without mutation.

---

You only need to copy the state when you want to update the property of state. For eg.:

```
// initial state
this.state = {
  settings: {
    a: 'value-1',
    b: 'color-green'
  }
}
```

Now, we have `a` and `b` property in `settings` state. So now, if you wanted to update the `a`, then you'll need to copy the `settings`:

```
this.setState((state) => ({settings: {...state.settings, a: 'value-2' } }))
```

The preceding example is with settings object. You can think similar with array of state. You may just do a google search for **how to update the array without mutation?**

Comment: Just to make sure I understood you correctly: so in the in the `getDerivedStateFromProps`, I can in fact just go with: `return ({state.setting_a: props.setting_a});` as well ? That is, without spreading the previous state.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
In your first case you could do:

```
this.setState( prevState => {  
    prevState.setting_a = "value-2";  
    return prevState
});
```

Or just go with:

```
this.setState({ setting_a: "value-2" });
```

As per [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) State Updates are Merged.

Comment: 'You could' but you shouldn't. The reason why we bother with `...state` spread is that state should remain immutable. Mutating may result in bugs. This is same as `this.state.setting_a = "value-2"; this.forceUpdate()`. This is possible but smells bad.

Comment: @estus you're confusing updating react's state and redux's store.
In case with redux you may not update the store, you must create a new object every time you need to change a property in it. But that's not the case with react.
Moreover, as per [React Docs] (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) you should not modify state directly, as you did with `this.state.setting_a = "value-2"`. Use `this.setState()` instead.

Comment: Immutability is the concept that is idiomatic to React in whole. In your example `this.state === state`. You're mutating it. The snippet you posted is generally safe (so is `this.state.setting_a = "value-2"; this.forceUpdate()`). Until you forget to return `state` from the function (or call `forceUpdate`, which is nearly same thing), this could easily happen. Then state update won't be triggered and you will end up with accidentally mutated state. That's why it should be avoided.

Comment: @estus "...is idiomatic to React in whole" - looks like that you know React better than it's creatures.